# why is "candidate function(s) not accessible" although declared public

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, vtk

I am getting compile error `candidate function(s) not accessible` when calling certain members, although I declared them as `public`.
I only get the error when some class from [vtk](http://www.vtk.org/) is involved (as return type or as argument) and when the class to be called is not in the same VS-project as the calling code. I also tried other vtk types with no luck :(

Here is some test code:

```
// A.h, in a seperate class library
#include <vtkActor.h>
public ref class A
{
public:
    A(void);

    void test1(vtkActor* actor);
    vtkActor* test2();
    void test3(char* actor);
    char* test4();
};


// B.h, Same as A but in the same project as the calling code 
#include <vtkActor.h>
ref class B
{
public:
    B(void);

    void test1(vtkActor* actor);
    vtkActor* test2();
    void test3(char* actor);
    char* test4();
};
```

I tried to call the functions from the same project `B` is in like this:

```
// calls to class library
A^ testA = gcnew A();    
testA ->test1(vtkActor::New());  // error
testA ->test2();                 // error
testA ->test3("");               // ok
testA ->test4();                 // ok

// calls to this project
B^ testB = gcnew B();
testB ->test1(vtkActor::New());  // ok
testB ->test2();                 // ok
testB ->test3("");               // ok
testB ->test4();                 // ok
```

In the two lines with //error this is the exact message:

```
error C3767: 'A::test1': candidate function(s) not accessible
```

How I can resolve this error? Why does it occur only on vtk-types?

kind regards,
richn

Comment: I'm not sure that it's the function, but memory access. Try moving **vtkActor::new()** outside of the function call.

Comment: Hi ChrisBD! That doesn't seem to be it :( I moved the initialization of the actor outside the method call, but it didn't change anyhting.

Comment: The vtkActor class is clearly the problem, did you declare it public?  Also watch out for header files, classes declared in another assembly should be imported by an assembly reference instead of a header file.

Comment: Hi Hans, the vtkActor class is not one of my own, its [a visualization library in native C++](http://http://www.vtk.org/). I imported it like this: I added all the .lib files I needed to `Project properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies`. Don't quite know if that is the right way, but it works fine as long as I call it from the same project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A short look at [C3767 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19dh8yat(v=vs.80).aspx) and the community comments shows:

> Another error-generating scenario
>
> Another thing that seems to generate this error is using a native type
>   in the signature of a public method, and then trying to call that
>   method from a different assembly.
>
> The solution here is to add a #pragma make_public on the native type,
>   after defining the native type but before defining the managed method
>   that uses it. The docs for #pragma make_public imply you're supposed
>   to get a compiler warning when a non-public native type is exposed by
>   a public managed type, but (at least with the default warning levels)
>   that does not seem to be the case.

Did you check that suggestion?

Comment: Thank you Werner, that did it! You're right, I really could have looked at that earlier...