# C++\CLI mixed mode DLL

Tags: .net, c++-cli, mixed-mode

I've a native C++ DLL that I want to convert into a managed DLL using the C++\CLI mixed-mode feature. I've written some code. The compilation of the DLL is fine, but the compilation of the executable that exploits the DLL fails with the

> error C3767 candidate function(s) not accessible

relative to the DLL's function I want to export. The structure of the code is the following

```
// -- DLL Header managedTest.h
namespace managedTest
{
    public ref class managedDLL
    {
    public:
        // -- Native function to export
        void SomeFunction(int a, USER-DEFINED TYPE &b);
    }
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

// -- DLL cpp file managedTest.cpp
#include "managedTest.h"
void managedTest::managedDLL::SomeFunction(int a, USER-DEFINED TYPE &b)
{
     do something;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

// -- Implementation file that recalls the DLL
using namespace managedTest;
int main(void)
{
     managedDLL^ test = gcnew managedDLL;
     test->SomeFunction(a, b); // -- Here I have the error!
}
```

I have read something about the calling of a function across a managed-unmanaged boundary, but I still can't find a solution to this problem. I'm almost sure the problem is related to making public the USER-DEFINED TYPE.

Could someone help me understand what is the problem? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the USER-DEFINED TYPE? A struct? A class? A typedef?

Comment: Not a public managed type by the sound of it.  So it can't be exported by the .NET metadata.  Which makes the exposed method inaccessible.  `#pragma make_public` might be a workaround but not often, wrap it as well..

Comment: Related: [C++ CLI error C3767: candidate function(s) not accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947213/c-cli-error-c3767-candidate-functions-not-accessible), [why is “candidate function(s) not accessible” although declared public](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400176/why-is-candidate-functions-not-accessible-although-declared-public)

Comment: @DavidYaw the USER-DEFINED TYPE is a struct.

Comment: @HansPassant I've already tried your suggestion about the #pragma but it didn't solve the problem. Is there no other way to solve the problem, either changing the structure of the program?

Comment: Please show the actual definition of the struct. To do this, it would need to be declared [public value struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke3a209d.aspx) and none of the public members can be standard C++ classes.

Comment: Why do you have to change the "structure of the program"?  Declaring a `public value class` to wrap the native structure is not different from declaring a `public ref class` to wrap the native class/functions.